# Getting input for linked list fgets & scanf C

Tags: c, arrays, linked-list, scanf, fgets

I created this linked list but I am having trouble getting the char array and the ints at the same time. Any suggestions? I have been up and down in forums and google but I can't seem to get it to agree with anything.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct node {
    int id;
    char name[40];
    struct node *next;
    struct node *prev;
} info;

int insert (int num, char *Name);
void print ();

struct node *root;   // Declare root a pointer to the first node

int main () {

    int n, Id, i;
    char nAme[40];
    char *name_ptr;

    root = NULL;      // List is empty

    printf ("How many list entries do you want to make?\n");

    scanf (" %d ", &n);
    n = 2;
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        printf ("Enter name: ");
        fgets (nAme, 40, stdin);
        printf ("Enter id number: ");
        scanf ("%d", &Id);
        name_ptr = &nAme[0];
        insert (Id, name_ptr);
        print ();
    }
}

int insert (int num, char *Name)
{
    // Get memory
    struct node *temp = (struct node *) malloc (sizeof (struct node));
    if (temp == NULL) {
        printf ("Some malloc problem.\n");
        return 1;
    }

    temp->id = num;
    strcpy (temp->name, Name);
    temp->next = root;
    root = temp;
}

void print ()
{
    struct node *temp = root;
    while (temp != NULL) {
        printf ("%d\n%s\n", temp->id, temp->name);
        temp = temp->next;
    }
    printf ("\n");
}
```

Sorry I'm a bit new to this site, so the formatting might say javascript, but its C as you can probably tell.

Comment: You should have `\n` in your `printf()`, so the text will print out right away.  Also, you need to check the return value of `fgets()`, it may be null which means it does not read anything.

Comment: *I'm having trouble* is not a meaningful problem description. It's clear you're having some sort of trouble, or you wouldn't need to be posting here. What **specific trouble** are you having? Also, *any suggestions* is not an answerable questions. We could have many suggestions, from *fix your code* to *buy a book* to *buy low, sell high* or *fertilize your lawn once a year*. What **specific question** related to your code would you like to ask?

Comment: Your linked list seems to be incomplete. You must link the nodes which you are not doing here.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of problems conspiring against you. The first, important, but not a show stopper, is `fgets` will read *up to and including the* `newline`. Which means all of your `nAme` (presuming you meant `name`) entries have an embedded newline at the end. This will cause all kinds of havok when you attempt to *search for* or *compare* specific names in your list.

A huge issue is you have no validation on whether you even receive input to add to your list from the user. *Always, always validate* user input. That means checking at minimum that you actually have input to store. e.g.

```
    printf ("Number of list entries to make?: ");

    if (scanf (" %d%*c", &n) != 1) {
        fprintf (stderr, "error: invalid no. of entries.\n");
        return 1;
    }

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        printf ("Enter name: ");
        if (!fgets (name, MAXC, stdin)) {
            fprintf (stderr, "error: invalid name.\n");
            return 1;
        }
        rmcrlf (name);     /* strip trailing newline from name */
        printf ("Enter id number: ");
        if (scanf ("%d%*c", &id) != 1) {
            fprintf (stderr, "error: invalid ID.\n");
            return 1;
        }
        insert (id, name);
    }
```

(**note:** the `rmcrlf` (remove carriage-return newline) function trims the trailing new line or erroneous carriage return from the name value)

The more substantive issues being apparent confusion on what type of list you are creating (*single/double* linked, traditional *head/tail*, *circular*, what?) The difference being that a traditional *head/tail* will use a `NULL` value to mark the end/beginning of the list, while a *circular* list points the last node to the first allowing iteration from any point around the list.

You appear to want a *doubly-linked* list with your `prev` and `next` pointers, but you make absolutely no attempt to handle the `prev` pointer in any way. It is unclear whether you want a *circular* or *head/tail* `NULL` list. Regardless which you choose, you must account for setting the values for your `prev` and `next` pointer with each `insert` you do. It makes a difference whether you are setting the `1st` (and `2nd` on a circular list) compared to the remaining insertions. The following is an example of the insert function that will correctly handle additions to a circular list. A head/tail `NULL` list does not need specific handling of the second node.

```
struct node *insert (int num, char *name)
{
    struct node *temp = malloc (sizeof *temp);  /* allocate node */
    if (!temp) {
        fprintf (stderr, "error: virtual memory exhausted.\n");
        exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    temp->id = num;
    strcpy (temp->name, name);

    if (!root) {    /* empty list - insert first node */
        temp->next = temp->prev = temp;
        root = temp;
    }
    else if (root == root->next) { /* insert 2nd node */
        temp->next = root;
        root->prev = temp;
        root->next = temp;
        temp->prev = root;
    }
    else {      /* insert all remaining nodes at end  */
        root->prev->next = temp;
        temp->prev = root->prev;
        temp->next = root;
        root->prev = temp;
    }

    return temp;
}
```

(**note:** the function type being `struct node *`. It is of little use to return an `int` value here. You can judge success/failure by returning `NULL` in the event of a failure and you have the inserted node available for any post-insert processing required. Also, do *NOT* cast the return of `malloc` and you need only take the `sizeof` the object pointed to by the pointer being allocated)

Don't use *magic numbers* in your code. They make the code harder to maintain. If you need a constant to set the maximum characters in `name`, then define one with `#define MAXC 40` or declare a global `enum` to define the constant (e.g. `enum { MAXC = 40 };`).

Putting those pieces together and fixing a few more nits, you could code your *doubly-linked circular list* something like the following example. You can simplify the code slightly by simply using a traditional *head/tail* `NULL` list instead.

Look the code over closely and understand the changes made (you need no `name_ptr` at all, and you don't set `n=2;` *after* taking input for `n` with `scanf`). Also note how the `'\n'` character `scanf` leaves in the *input buffer* (e.g. `stdin`) is handled. If you fail to account for the `'\n'`, you will find `scanf` skipping over your input due to it taking the `'\n'` left in the input buffer as your input.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAXC 40

struct node {
    int id;
    char name[MAXC];
    struct node *next;
    struct node *prev;
} info;

struct node *insert (int num, char *name);
void print (void);
void delete_list (void);
void rmcrlf (char *s);

struct node *root;  /* Declare root a pointer to the first node */

int main (void) {

    int i, id, n;
    char name[MAXC];

    root = NULL;    /* List is empty */

    printf ("Number of list entries to make?: ");

    if (scanf (" %d%*c", &n) != 1) {
        fprintf (stderr, "error: invalid no. of entries.\n");
        return 1;
    }

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        printf ("Enter name: ");
        if (!fgets (name, MAXC, stdin)) {
            fprintf (stderr, "error: invalid name.\n");
            return 1;
        }
        rmcrlf (name);
        printf ("Enter id number: ");
        if (scanf ("%d%*c", &id) != 1) {
            fprintf (stderr, "error: invalid ID.\n");
            return 1;
        }
        insert (id, name);
    }
    print();
    delete_list();

    return 0;
}

struct node *insert (int num, char *name)
{
    struct node *temp = malloc (sizeof *temp);  /* allocate node */
    if (!temp) {
        fprintf (stderr, "error: virtual memory exhausted.\n");
        exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    temp->id = num;
    strcpy (temp->name, name);

    if (!root) {    /* empty list - insert first node */
        temp->next = temp->prev = temp;
        root = temp;
    }
    else if (root == root->next) { /* insert 2nd node */
        temp->next = root;
        root->prev = temp;
        root->next = temp;
        temp->prev = root;
    }
    else {      /* insert all remaining nodes at end  */
        root->prev->next = temp;
        temp->prev = root->prev;
        temp->next = root;
        root->prev = temp;
    }

    return temp;
}

void print (void)
{
    struct node *temp = root;

    printf ("\n  Id     Name\n ----    ---------------------\n");
    while (temp->next != root) {
        printf (" %4d    %s\n", temp->id, temp->name);
        temp = temp->next;
    }
    printf (" %4d    %s\n", temp->id, temp->name);
    printf ("\n");
}

/* free memory for all nodes in list */
void delete_list (void)
{
    struct node *temp = root->next;
    while (temp != root) {
        struct node *victim = temp;
        temp = temp->next;
        free (victim);
    }
    if (temp) free (temp);
}

/** stip trailing newlines by overwriting with null-terminating char.
 *  str is modified in place.
 */
void rmcrlf (char *s)
{
    if (!s || !*s) return;
    for (; *s && *s != '\n'; s++) {}
    *s = 0;
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/ll_double_cir
Number of list entries to make?: 3
Enter name: cats
Enter id number: 3
Enter name: dogs
Enter id number: 17
Enter name: mice
Enter id number: 123

  Id     Name
 ----    ---------------------
    3    cats
   17    dogs
  123    mice
```

**Memory Use/Error Check**

In any code your write that dynamically allocates memory, you have 2 *responsibilities* regarding any block of memory allocated: (1) *always preserve a pointer to the starting address* for the block of memory so, (2) it can be *freed* when it is no longer needed.

It is imperative that you use a memory error checking program to insure you haven't written beyond/outside your allocated block of memory, attempted to read or base a jump on an unintitialized value and finally to confirm that you have freed all the memory you have allocated. For Linux `valgrind` is the normal choice. Usage is simple, just run your code through it and check the results:

```
$ valgrind ./bin/ll_double_cir
==14595== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==14595== Copyright (C) 2002-2013, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==14595== Using Valgrind-3.10.1 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==14595== Command: ./bin/ll_double_cir
==14595==
Number of list entries to make?: 3
Enter name: cats
Enter id number: 3
Enter name: dogs
Enter id number: 17
Enter name: mice
Enter id number: 123

  Id     Name
 ----    ---------------------
    3    cats
   17    dogs
  123    mice

==14595==
==14595== HEAP SUMMARY:
==14595==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==14595==   total heap usage: 3 allocs, 3 frees, 192 bytes allocated
==14595==
==14595== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==14595==
==14595== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==14595== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 1 from 1)
```

Always confirm *All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible* and equally important *ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts*.

Look over the changes and if you have any questions, just ask.

Answer (score -1):

What is is not doing?

Lookign at the code:

root should be initialized to NULL.

insert could be called as inert(Id, nName); instread of insert(Id, name_ptr);

in  insert, you should initalize ->prev = NULL;

Comment: root has been initialized to NULL in the main function if you see carefully

Comment: the other 2 comments are still valid though